# Possible to make a shorter encryption string then openssl_encrypts gives me

Tags: php

So I have been trying to read up on encryption, but is is very large area and I have a hard time finding a simple "do your own encryption algorithm".

The thing is that my friend is starting a diet, and we want to keep track of his weight by weigh him every singel morning and make a chart of his progress in the end. But in the same time, don't give any information on how his diet currently is going, so we thought that we encrypt the value!

So his weight will probably start of on there (3) digits, and (hopefully) end up on two (2) digits. And for convenience we don't want a silly long string. Just a simple three-four digit encrypted string.

So I have this code at the moment:

```
class hash {
    protected $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC"; 
    protected $secretHash = "432556785785875098";

    public function weightHasher($weight){
        if(!is_numeric($weight)){
            return 'Must be numbers';
        }
        return openssl_encrypt($weight, $this->encryptionMethod, $this->secretHash);
    }

    public function weightDeHasher($weight){
        return openssl_decrypt($weight, $this->encryptionMethod, $this->secretHash);
    }
}
```

But its a insane long encrypted string for this purpose!

Is there another method? Or how can I make one (not so secure) algorithm to give me a shorter encrypted string?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a hard time finding a simple "do your own encryption algorithm".

Because you're not supposed to do that. Cryptography is hard and anybody that actually needs it should seek existing, proven algorithms and the help of professionals.
And for good reason - your sample code lacks a lot of *mandatory* components for a sane encryption algorithm (IV, authentication, a *proper* key, and more).

Seems like you're doing a harmless toy project here, but I urge you to follow the advice above.

That being said, length is affected by 2 things here:

- `openssl_encrypt()` will return the cipherText Base64-encoded by default, which makes it about 30% larger. However, since the original cipherText would be a raw binary string (which is unreadable to you, hard to store, etc.), there's no reason to change that really - 30% is certainly better than the 100% you'd get with regular `bin2hex()`.
- CBC mode, being a *block*-based mode, will always have an output with size divisible by the block size of the algorithm in use (that's 128 bits or 16 bytes for AES). Stream ciphers don't act like this, so you should pick one such if you care about saving bandwidth; I'd use CTR.